# $p$-capacity of the closure

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, calculus-of-variations, potential-theory

The $p$-capacity of a condenser $(K,\Omega)$ with $K$ compact and $\Omega$ open bounded is defined as
$$
\mathrm{Cap}_p(K,\Omega)=\inf \left\lbrace \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p \mathrm{d} x : u \in \mathscr{C}_c^\infty (\Omega), u \geq 1 \text{ on } K\right\rbrace.
$$
As reported by [Heinonen, Kilpeläinen, Martio](http://users.jyu.fi/%7Eterok/NLPT/NLPT_dover.pdf) one can define the $p$-capacity of a general subset $E \subseteq \Omega$ by taking
$$
\mathrm{Cap}_p(E,\Omega)=\inf\left\lbrace\mathrm{Cap}^*_p(A,\Omega) : E\subset A \subset \Omega, A\text{ open}\right\rbrace
$$
where $\mathrm{Cap}^*_p$ is defined for every set $A$ as
$$
\mathrm{Cap}^*_p(A,\Omega)=\sup\left\lbrace\mathrm{Cap}_p(K,\Omega) : K\subset A , K\text{ compact}\right\rbrace.
$$
Such definition is well-posed and coincides with the first one on compact subsets. Then the authors specify that in general $\mathrm{Cap}_p(A,\Omega)$ does not coincides with $\mathrm{Cap}_p(\overline{A},\Omega)$ if $A$ is a open set such that $\overline{A} \subset \Omega$. They prove the identity for the ball as a consequence of a Wiener type boundary estimate. So the question is, for which open subsets $A$ as above the two quantities coincide? I imagine that some regularity for the boundary is required, but I did not find any reference.

EDIT: Do the two quantities coincide if $A$ has smooth boundary?